# For-cycle through filtered list

Tags: python

I have the code

```
for item in list:
    if item.some_boolean_property():
        several complicated commands here
```

I want to squash these `for` and `if` into one expression, so that the commands can be less indented by one level. I was able to refactor this into the code

```
for item in [item for item in list if item.some_boolean_property()]:
    several complicated commands here
```

It does work, but, you know, it is ugly. :) Is there any smarter way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just filter the list beforehand, so you can directly use for loop without if condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save one indentation level, use `continue` to skip the iteration you're not interested in:

```
for item in list:
    if not item.some_boolean_property():
        continue # skip this iteration

    # several complicated commands here,
    # one indentation level less than above!
```

Comment: you just use if item.some_boolean_property() without need to use continue

Comment: @BelhadjerSamir did you read the question? That is what OP does. They want to save an indent

Comment: @BelhadjerSamir, the point is to _remove one level of indentation_, but `if item.some_boolean_property():` does the exact opposite, as seen in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`filter` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), but it's not any less ugly than your list comprehension.  And a generator is the preferred way these days.

```
for item in filter(lambda x: x.some_boolean_property(), list):
    several complicated commands here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that with while loop :

```
list=iter(list_origin)
element=next(list,None) if list_origin[0].some_boolean_property() else None
while(element.some_boolean_property()):
    # several complicated commands here,
    element=next(list,None)
```